# Race condition while adding items

Tags: react-native

This function is called by a firebase function for each new element.
There are multiple items in the database, however I see only one. I believe, this is because callbackAdded is called for every item without pause and the array copying is not working as I intend to.

I need to achieve to get all items be placed in data.
How can this be improved?

```
useEffect(() => {
    fb.getCorals(reef, callbackAdded, callbackChanged, callbackDeleted)
  }, []);

const [data, setData] = useState([]);

const callbackAdded = function(item) {
     const copy = [...data];
     copy.push(item);
     setData(
         copy
     );
  }
```

Comment: You are right, if you call callbackAdded many times within a single component render, it will keep overwriting data. I can't definitively give a solution without seeing getCorals, but probably you want callbackAdded to accept a list of items, and spread those new items into data. Then you only have to call it once for each db fetch.

Comment: This looks like it should work. Can you confirm that `callbackAdded` is called multiple times?